# Find out the parts of my FORTRAN project which were not unit-tested

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, fortran

i am currently switching to funit to fully test my rather big Fortran-Project. 
Is there a tool that allows me to find out which lines of my project were not 
yet tested? I use emacs, so is there a simple script that would allow me to 
easily see which parts of my file are not yet tested?

I could imagine recruiting the -prof compiler for something like that, but 
i am just starting out. So i definitely cannot do this on my own.

Comment: Investigate the support that your compiler provides for *code coverage*.

Comment: thanks ! that helps me a ton. Any way i can use this in emacs every compile or so, to get a quick overview while coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your compiler. I use Intel Fortran on Linux for testing purposes, and its coverage checking options. Compile and link your code with something like

```
ifort -g -prof-gen=srcpos ...
```

(Side note: parallel make does not work for me with `-prof-gen` option enabled) The compilation will produce some extra files in your sources directory. Run the tests, each program execution will produce a `*.dyn` file in you sources directory. After running all the tests execute

```
profmerge
proforder
codecov
```

This will produce a nice detailed HTML-formatted coverage report. Don't forget to delete old `*.dyn` and `pgopti.dpi*` files before running new series of tests, otherwise you will see an intersection of different coverage results.